# npm link is not working, bash: dosmth: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I am trying to do basic CLI with node, but seems like it is not linking from/to correct directory.

I have file named **create**, which contains command: `console.log(process.cwd());`

When I run in bash `node create`, it gives me that outcome: 
`/Users/katya/Desktop/code/drawer`.

However, after running `npm link` (or `sudo npm link`), it prints that:

```
/Users/katya/.npm-packages/bin/dosmth -> /Users/katya/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/drawer/create
/Users/katya/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/drawer -> /Users/katya/Desktop/code/drawer
```

and after that if I run `dosmth` in bash I get:

```
bash: dosmth: command not found
```

I assume there is something to do with `./npm-packages/` appearing in the path.

I tried to delete node completely from computer and install again but did not help.

If you have any idea I would really appreciate your help.

My **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "drawer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "dosmth": "create"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Since yesterday I have: 
1. Installed **brew**
2. Installed/uninstalled **Node** on mac (now with **Brew**)
3. Run ```rm -rf``` and ```sudo rm -rf``` on all node related directories
Still, when I am running ```npm link``` or ```sudo npm link``` it does not pick up the necessary directory and says ```bash: my-command: command not found```.

Would really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you so much, 

Katya

Comment: Did you ever solve this? (I ask because I believe I have the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing bin to point to your index.js?

```
{
    // Other keys ...
    "bin": {
        "dosmth": "./index.js"
    },
    //...
}
```